add card number to zkteco user with python and pyzk
I recently purchased a ZKTeco Uface800 Plus device. I've developed a small Python application to manage it, allowing me to connect, add users, and enroll fingerprints using the PyZK library. When the PyZK method zk.enroll_user(uuid, fingernumber) is executed, it prompts the user to place their finger on the fingerprint reader three times, registering their fingerprint into the device.
Now, I'm looking to implement similar functionality for RFID cards. I need a function enroll_card(uuid) that, when executed, prompts the user with the specified UUID to swipe their RFID card on the device, registering the card number.
Alternatively, I'm also interested in a simpler method to just read the RFID number of a card and print it. For example, a method like zk.set_user(uuid=1, card=card_number) could be used for this purpose."
I attempted to replicate the functionality of the zk.enroll_user method from PyZK for RFID cards. However, I found this task challenging as I'm new to Python and ZKTeco

Did you figure out this problem? I face the same problem and unfortunately, I can't solve the problem.

i did not find a solution
